# Create and share Google Drive folders dynamically

Tags: asp.net, google-drive-api

I have a list of emails.

For each email, I need to create a Google Drive folder and share it with the given email.

How can I do it programmically?

I am using ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: Google it.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you need to make sure you have application with clientid/secret and correct redirect uri configured. For my case - it's a desktop application:

[image]

So far you'll get clientId/secret key:

[image]

Now it's time to write some codes!

Step 1 - authorization:

```
private async static Task<UserCredential> Auth(ClientSecrets clientSecrets)
{   
    return await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(clientSecrets, Scopes, "user", CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Step 2 - construct your client for google drive:

```
private static DriveService GetService(UserCredential credential)
{
    return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "MyApplicationName",
    });
}
```

Step 3 - create folder (or any other content):

```
private static string CreateFolder(DriveService service, string folderName)
{
    var file = new File {Title = folderName, MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"};
    var result = service.Files.Insert(file).Execute();
    return result.Id;
}
```

Step 4 - share it!

```
/// <summary>
/// Share content. Doc link: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert
/// </summary>  
private static void Share(DriveService service, string fileId, string value, string type, string role)
{
    var permission = new Permission {Value = value, Type = type, Role = role};
    service.Permissions.Insert(permission, fileId).Execute();
}
```

And finally usage of whole thing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ClientId = "MySecredId";
    var SecretKey = "MySecretKey";

    var Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile, DriveService.Scope.Drive };

    var secrets = new ClientSecrets { ClientId = ClientId, ClientSecret = SecretKey };
    var credentials = Auth(secrets).Result;

    var service = GetService(credentials);

    var folderId = CreateFolder(service, "folderName");

    Share(service, folderId, "user@gmail.com", "user", "reader");
}
```

For list of emails you can do pretty same thing creating/sharing content in a loop for every email you have.

Some usefull links:

[Creating files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert)

[Sharing files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert)

**Also**
You'll need [Google.Apis.Drive.v2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/) nuget package

Comment: Where is `DriveService`  found?

Comment: The same goes for `File` and `Permission`.

Comment: @Endri it's all Google.Apis.Drive.v2. Install that package for solution (it has bunch of dependencies)

Comment: well played @Sergio, well played

Comment: @KodeKreachor did I miss something?

Comment: No worries @Endri , just giving props for a great answer :)

Answer (score 4):

The steps to perform this hinge on authenticating with Google first. Once you've done that you'll be able to access the Drive API to perform the actions you'd like. The following links walk you through everything you need to do.

Step 1: Authenticate (server side in your case as you're using ASP.NET)
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server

Step 2: Create your folders
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/folder

Step 3: Share your folders
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-sharing

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in below link. It have full course on Google Drive !!

https://www.codeschool.com/courses/discover-drive

Comment: That is in Ruby. I am looking for a ASP.net + C# Approach!

Comment: its simply with html and java script and you can easily convert that in ASP.net !!